# How to handler onClick on child component in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

my App component like as below:

```
class App extends Component {
  clickHandler = () => {
    console.log('click');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>Test1</div>
        <Person onClick={this.clickHandler}>Test2</Person>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

And this is my Person component:

```
class Person extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

When i click on `Test1` onClick works and show click on console, but when i click on `Test2` onClick doesn't work.
how to i handler onClick in parent component? i don't want pass onClick to child component.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass `onClick` to the child component? That's pretty much how React works, although there are different ways to get properties in children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. Why don't you want to write it this way? You ARE passing it as a prop...

```
<div onClick={props.onClick}>Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution...
Checkout: https://codesandbox.io/s/vjp200rj3

Modified render function in App.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>Test1</div>
        <Person clickHandler={this.clickHandler}>Test2</Person>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Modified render function in Person:

```
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `onClick` to the `<div>` in `Person`.

`onClick` is not a special prop that works everywhere in React - The only intrinsic props are `key` and `children`. Everything else needs to be wired up manually.

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're passing `onClick` to `Person`, but to the `Person` component, `onClick` is just another prop. It does nothing on it's own until you pass it to a component that understands what it means to handle a click event (which all of the built-in components in React do).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={propes.onClick}>{props.children}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please add an explanation, highlighting parts of your answer that addresses OP's issue, & why/how. Code only answers are generally frowned upon on SO.  Adding details adds to long term value, & helps future visitors learn, so they can apply this knowledge to their own coding issues. Also, it improves quality of the answer, & hence SO as well. Higher quality answers are upvoted more often, as more users find them a good resource to refer back to. Consider editing to provide additional info, explain why you chose this approach, or highlight what OP needed to change.